# My program runs fine in Eclipse but throws exception running as a jar file

Tags: java, eclipse

My small program runs fine in Eclipse but it won't run after exporting and running as a jar file. Here is the exception it throws when run. (I might just need a link to a good article on exporting to a jar file). Thanks for helping.

---

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/swt/widge
ts/Layout
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Layout
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: EnterNames.EnterNames. Program will exit.
*******
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program is making use of classes which are part of the Eclipse product. You need to either change your code to not use these classes, or identify the jars these classes are in and make sure that they are part of the classpath for your program. Then as @irrelephant says, you can setup a manifest or you can set them in a command line classpath parameter.

Comment: I finally got it. Here's what I did. I followed the above suggestions (links to the Eclipse FAQ) And I also found the jar files which I needed to list in the Manifest.MF file - they were listed in the package explorer under JRE Reference Library. Adding them to the Manifest.mf File finally was the key.
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: org.EnterNames.EnterNames
Class-Path: swt.jar
  java\jre6\resources.jar
  java\jre6\rt.jar
  java\jre6\jsse.jar
  java\jre6\jce.jar
  java\jre6\dnsns.jar
  java\jre6\QTJava.zip
  java\jre6\sunjce_provider.jar
  
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

> (I might just need a link to a good article on exporting to a jar file)

It is not that straightforward.  If your application has a dependencies on SWT classes, then you need to configure your application to use SWT outside of Eclipse.  It is not just a matter of adding the right JAR files.  SWT uses native libraries to talk to the host OS's windowing system.

This [Eclipse FAQ](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_create_an_executable_JAR_file_for_a_stand-alone_SWT_program%3F) describes how to create a JAR for a standalone SWT-based application.

Comment: I'm still going in circles. I tried your suggestions (all three of you) and still hit the same wall. I don't even have "org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Layout" as an import and if I try to find that in the intellisence I don't find it. The error I get at the end of the export is- Exported with compile warnings:

Comment: Also - Derek mentions identifying the Jars. How do I know which ones I used there are dozens in eclipse. I don't see where the ones I use might be listed

Answer (score 0):

You need the SWT class in your jar file. Include the `swt.jar` in your jar file, and follow [this entry on eclipse faq](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_create_an_executable_JAR_file_for_a_stand-alone_SWT_program%3F).